# Most efficient way to count number of pairs in an array whose product is a perfect square?

Tags: java

My solution was this:

To take all possible pairs (not the one which had same elements as the question demanded) , then check first element to be perfect square if true 
check the other element to be perfect square.

Checking for perfect square was simply getting square root and checking fractional part.

I was asked this in an interview but it was required to be better.
Can anyone give me a better approach.

```
int cnt = 0.0;
for (int i = 0; i < test; i++)  {
    for (int j = 0; j < test; j++)  {
        if (!(i == j))  {
            double prod = Math.sqrt(arr[i]);
            int prodi = (int) prod;
            double frac = prod - prodi;
            if (frac == 0.0) {
                //System.out.println("SAdfs");
                prod=Math.sqrt(arr[j]);
                prodi = (int)prod;
                frac = prod-prodi;
                if (frac == 0.0) {
                    cnt++;
                }
            }
        }       
    }
}

double denom=test*(test-1);
double result=cnt/denom;
String strDouble = String.format("%.6f", result);
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: How big are the numbers in the array?

Comment: BTW, your algorithm doesn't work - 2 isn't a perfect square, but 2*2 is. So you can't check the first and second numbers independently.

Comment: Yeah 2*2 is surely 4, a perfect square but the question required that no two elements chosen would be same.

Comment: @Andy the numbers could be as big as 10^5 .

Comment: The requirement that the numbers are different is not apparent from the question.

Comment: Yeah sorry , forgot to mention that.

Comment: But it also doesn't work for `6 * 2400 = (2 * 3 * 4 * 5)^2`.

Comment: Thank you for that. Well now i need a full new algorithm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to find the factorials of both inputs, and their counts, like

```
12 = 2 ^ 2, 3 ^ 1;
27 = 3 ^ 3;
```

Then you need to sum the factorial factors of both inputs (for example I gave, would be 2:2, 3:4). If all factorials have a factor divisible by 2 (ie factor % 2 == 0) then it is a perfect square

Comment: I think you meant prime factorisation and not factorial!

Answer (score 1):

I have a few clarifications with your solution. However, if I m understanding your question correctly, you need this

Input array: {1,2,3,4,5,20,25}
Output: 4 different pairs 
They are: {1,4},{1,25},{4,25},{5,20}

The solution below uses your logic of identifying the perfect square (sqrt and double - int value ==0.0). But the logic to count the pairs is implemented.

```
public class PerfectSq {



    public static List<NumbPairs> count(int[] input)
    {


        List<NumbPairs> pairs = new ArrayList<NumbPairs>();

        for(int i = 0;i<input.length;i++)
        {
            for(int j = (i+1);j<input.length;j++)
            {
                if(i!=j)
                {
                    if(isPerfectSquare(input[i]*input[j]))
                    {

                        pairs.add(new NumbPairs(input[i],input[j]));

                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return pairs;
    }


    private static boolean isPerfectSquare(int i)
    {


            double sqr = Math.sqrt(i);
            int sq = (int) sqr;
            return ((sqr-sq)==0.0);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] input = new int[5];
        input = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,25,20};

        List<NumbPairs> numbPairs = count(input);

        System.out.println(numbPairs );

        System.out.println(numbPairs.size());


    }
}

class NumbPairs
{
    int i;
    int j;

    public NumbPairs(int i, int j)
    {
        this.i = i;
        this.j = j;

    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return i+","+j+" ";

    }
}
```

You could improve it little bit more by adding this, so that it does not have to check if the number if perfect square or not if it has already been computed. This would be useful in a larger array size.

```
public static Map<Integer, Boolean> map = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();

private static boolean isPerfectSquare(int i)
    {

        Boolean square = map.get(i);

        if(square!=null)
        {
            return square;
        }
        else
        {
            double sqr = Math.sqrt(i);
            int sq = (int) sqr;
            return ((sqr-sq)==0.0);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the first element **has to be perfect square** you should check it before entering the second loop (j). If you don't need to check the second number if the first one is not perfect square, then why do you do it?

If the arrays are long and numbers are big this would extend execution of given code noticeably.

```
int cnt=0.0;
for(int i=0;i<test;i++)
{
double prod=Math.sqrt(arr[i]);
      int prodi=(int)prod;
      double frac=prod-prodi;
      if(frac==0.0){
        for(int j=0;j<test;j++)
        {
           if(!(i==j))
            {

                    //System.out.println("SAdfs");
                     prod=Math.sqrt(arr[j]);
                    prodi=(int)prod;
                     frac=prod-prodi;
                   if(frac==0.0){
                    cnt++;
                   }
            }
        }       
    }
}
double denom=test*(test-1);
double result=cnt/denom;
String strDouble = String.format("%.6f", result);
System.out.println(result);
```